# Transistor parrallel to Voltage Regulator

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I'm encounter following schematic in a product.
[image]
It gets 110VAC and provide 5V DC to the board. After many inspection I still can't understand what Q2 and R4 do in this design.

First of all after T1, Voltage down convert to 27.5 volt. If we assume D1, R3 and D2 reduce at most, Vin at Voltage Regulator will at least be 25V in no load which is very higher than LM123 Vin Absolute Maximum (Specified 20V in [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm323-n.pdf))

And another mystery is, if we assume 5V at the LM123 output, Base-Emitter junction of Q2 will have 20V on it :|. So IMO either of Q2 or LM123 will explode.

So the question is where am I going wrong?

Comment: The base emitter junction only has 20 V across it if there is no drop across R3 or D2.

Comment: If we assume 3A output current for LM123 (Maximum Output Current), It makes sense. But what is the purpose of Q2 and R4 in the first place?

Comment: This is one of those crappy designs floating around on the internet.

Comment: I'd mostly imagine the schematic doesn't reflect what is in the product. Not that it matters, but off-hand out of vague curiosity what's the value of \$R_5\$?

Comment: To me, this only makes sense if you know a lot about the load, and if "+5V" is just a hint.

Comment: Here is a useful link about it. Scroll down to the title "Pass transistor". It basically says, the purpose is to provide the extra current which regulator cannot. http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/TheTransistorAmplifier/TheTransistorAmplifier-P2.html

Comment: @packt except that's a pnp circuit, which makes more sense... sort of.

Comment: @packt Not only a lousy page with quotes like "Obviously the circuit has never been tested", but it doesn't even explain why it's an NPN. The website shows PNP.

Comment: @jonk This design is a part of demo project (80C51 Board) in Cadence Orcad suits. I inspect the design for value of \$R_5\$ . And sorry we are out of luck. The design seems to be dummy at first glance, nevertheless I beleive the designer have something in mind for the schematic. packt comment solve one of these mystery and I hope that other part will solve eventually.

Comment: @pazel1374 If you mean that the BJT should be a PNP instead of an NPN, sure. Then it is possible if you consider the device to be in reverse-active mode. What's the "other part?" (Outside of my \$R_5\$ question, I mean.)

Comment: I'm not claiming anything about the quality of the entire web page btw. But the explanation made sense, so I just wanted to share. Not sure if it's the correct explanation either. Npn transistor doesn't make much difference I think. In the webpage's example, the voltage rises over the base resistor as the load current increases. If we assume applying same principle here, when the load current increases voltage rises on LM123 and transistor turns on providing extra current. And maybe diode is there to adjust the operating point to desired level. But again that's just an assumption.

Comment: @jonk R4 and D2, BTW look like you missing me to someone else as I dont made any comment on pnp or npn :)

Comment: Should I be disturbed that the ground pin isn't directly connected to ground?

Comment: Assuming that pot is kept at the bottom end it doesn't actually do anything other than charge up both caps. **Note there is no ground connection anywhere....** so there is zero current though R5. Pot at the top end it will let out a bit of smoke though.

Comment: "*After many inspection I still can't understand what Q2 and R4 do in this design.*"  For a npn, they do absolutely nothing - the design is faulty.

Comment: "nevertheless I beleive the designer have something in mind for the schematic." - I bet the 'something in mind' was deliberate errors to make the circuit unworkable.